# Codepen menu works fine, but doesn't work on a blank page

Tags: menu, codepen

I created a CSS/JS dropdown menu I am working on in Codepen. The menu works fine in Codepen:
https://codepen.io/jabbamonkey/pen/EXNQYB

However, when I place everything onto a blank php page ... the code doesn't work:
http://tbsmb.school/_temp.php

Any idea what is going wrong?

MENU CODE:

```
    <div id="mainmenu">
    <ul id="menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-143" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children first menu-item-143"><a href="#">About</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-113" class="menuico-apple menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-113"><a href="/about/welcome/">Welcome</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-114" class="menuico-vision menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-114"><a href="/about/vision/">Vision</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-115" class="menuico-approach menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-115"><a href="/about/approach/">Approach</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-116" class="menuico-team menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-116"><a href="/about/administration/">Administration</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-117" class="menuico-press menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-117"><a href="/about/press/">Press</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-118" class="menuico-employ menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-118"><a href="/about/employment/">Employment</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-119" class="menuico-resources menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-119"><a href="/about/resources/">Resources</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-120" class="menuico-contact menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-120"><a href="/about/contact/">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-144" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-144"><a href="#">Admissions</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-142" class="menuico-visit menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-142"><a href="/admissions/visit-us/">Visit Us</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-121" class="menuico-enroll menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-121"><a href="/admissions/enrollment/">Enrollment</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-122" class="menuico-tuition menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-122"><a href="/admissions/tuition/">Tuition</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-123" class="menuico-fineprint menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-123"><a href="/admissions/fine-print/">Fine Print</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-124" class="menuico-faq menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-124"><a href="/admissions/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-145" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-145"><a href="#">Programs</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-146" class="menuico-afterschool menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-146"><a href="/programs/after-school/">After-School</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-147" class="menuico-camp menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-147"><a href="/programs/camp/">Camp</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-149" class="menuico-parentchild menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-149"><a href="/programs/parent-child/">Parent-Child</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-148" class="menuico-parenttobe menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-148"><a href="/programs/parents-to-be/">Parents-to-be</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-150" class="menuico-family menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-150"><a href="/programs/family/">Family</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-151" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-151"><a href="#">Support</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-152" class="menuico-pto menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-152"><a href="/support/pto/">PTO</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-153" class="menuico-give menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-153"><a href="/support/ways-to-give/">Ways to Give</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-154" class="menuico-schol menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-154"><a href="/support/scholarships/">Scholarships</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-155" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page last menu-item-155"><a href="/calendar/">Calendar</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.menu li > .sub-menu').parent().click(function() {
  var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
  if ( $(submenu).is(':hidden') ) {
    $(submenu).slideDown(200);
  } else {
    $(submenu).slideUp(200);
  }
});
```

STYLES

```
.menu { vertical-align:middle; text-align:left; padding: 0 0 0 8px; margin: 0; list-style: none; position:relative; }
  .menu li { position:relative; font-size:24px; display:inline-block; padding:0; line-height:1; vertical-align:top; margin:0; } 
  .menu li a { display:block; padding:32px 25px 30px 25px; margin:0; color:#282828; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; }
  /* Hover */
  .menu li:hover > a { color: #282828; background-color:#c3def1; }

/* Sub-menu */
/* .menu li:hover > ul { display: block; } */
.menu .sub-menu { display:none; }
.menu .sub-menu { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 86px; left:0px; z-index: 99999; background-color:#87bde4; }
    .menu ul li { float: none; margin:0; padding:0; display: block; font-size: 22px; text-align: left; }
    .menu ul li a { border:0; text-transform:none;  }
    .menu ul a { padding: 22px 16px 17px 46px !important; min-width: 280px; height: auto; line-height: 1; display: block; color:#282828; }
    .menu ul a:hover { background-color:#9ac9eb; }

/* Hide Tertiary Menus */
.menu ul ul { display:none; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The site has not been instructed as to WHEN this code is relevant. In codepen, the code in the javascript area is assumed to run when the code is run, unless instructed otherwise.

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu li > .sub-menu').parent().click(function() {
      var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
      if ( $(submenu).is(':hidden') ) {
        $(submenu).slideDown(200);
      } else {
        $(submenu).slideUp(200);
      }
    });
});
```